# why does output of all shell commands include weird characters around the name of the command

Tags: shell, zsh

Every time I type a command the output includes the name of the command wrapped in strange characters:

```
➜  ~ pwd
kpwd\/home/alec
➜  ~ whoami
kwhoami\alec
➜  ~ echo $SHELL
kecho\/usr/bin/zsh
```

[image]

I guess it would make more sense for line breaks to be inserted around the name of the command, or just not printing the name of the command at all.  But I don't know how to achieve either.

Help please?

Comment: probably a broken prompt setup. does it happen under `zsh -f`? if not, bisect your zsh configuration until you find the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line from .zshrc was causing the problem.

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

Comment: ... because you were telling your applications, including the Z shell, that your terminal type was the `screen` program when it was not.

Comment: Oh!  I didn't realize that 'screen' in that case was referring the the `screen` program!  Thanks!